# meaning of "relatively unspectacular"

Tags: american-english, british-english

What is the meaning of relatively unspectacular in below sentence?

Other planets in the solar system are quite beyond habitation, because their temperature is far too high or too low to be endured, and ours, too, in principle could tip either way. Even relatively unspectacular changes in the atmosphere could do the trick.

Comment: While, "above" is an adjective in addition to being a preposition, "below" is not. "Below" is only a preposition, not an adjective. So, while people say "in the *above* sentence," "above" being an adjective in that sentence, people **do not** say "in the *below* sentence" but only "in the sentence *below*." That's because "below" is not an adjective, is only a preposition, and so is only said after the noun it relates to, not before. You put it before. Don't.

Answer (score 1):

"Relatively unspectacular"
First, the prefix "un-" means the meaning of the root word is negated.
The root word is defined here:

[American Heritage Dictionary "spectacular"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spectacular)

> Of the nature of a spectacle; impressive or sensational.

So, *unspectacular* means not impressive or sensational, that is something that might not be noticed at first, for example, and increase of a few tenths of a percent in CO2 concentration.

"Relatively" means that the changes are not impressive, compared to other changes.

Comment: but what comparison is taking place here? Am I missing anything?